# Is there a cross-platform way to set the desktop background in Java?

Tags: java

I've been creating an app that sets the user's desktop background. I can only find how to set the background for Windows and Mac. Is there any way to do it in Linux and, more importantly, is there a single method or library for all desktop environments?

Comment: It's similar to the first question, but the "answer" there only tells you how to determine what OS you run on.

Comment: Correct.  The answer only addresses what is not already answered by the links in the question itself.  Try reading those.  (To do it in Linux, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/50019/how-do-i-change-the-desktop-background-from-command-line.)

Comment: I already checked out the links, I appreciate it though. I was wondering if there was a truly cross-platform method or library instead of finding each Linux distro and making my own. Probably too good to be true, but I just wanted to check